# jquery post variable shows in html but not php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, post

I'm not sure if it's just me or what but this seems really odd. When I click a button I have jquery send out javascript variables to a php site to be handled there. However on the php site they come up as undefined indexes. The weird part, is that they show on the html page through php's echo. NOTE: The html button is an input type="button", not a submit because I don't want to reload the page.

jquery:

```
var timestampst = $(timestamp).val();

var objNamest = $(objInst).val();

$.post("sendCalc.php", {
    postobjNamest:objInst,
    posttimestampst:timestamp},
function(data){
    $("#divResult").html(data);
});
```

php:

```
//used for troubleshooting, returns Array() on the php page and Array (  [posttimestampst] => 1399973296 [postobjNamest] => test2-1
print_r($_POST);

//when the if and else are used it the php page always echos Not Working, meaning that the $_POST is not set somehow. However, the html page shows the echoed variables in the "divResult" as it should.

//when I try the code without the if and else, the php page returns Undefined Index: posttimstamp/postobjNamest. However, the html page still shows the echoed variables.

if(isset($_POST["posttimestampst"])){
    $timestamp = $_POST["posttimestampst"];
    echo $timestamp;
    echo "<br>";

    $objName = $_POST["postobjNamest"];
    echo $objName;
    echo "<br>";
}
else{
    echo "Not Working";
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

```
//gets selected object from a dropdown menu
selectedObj = document.getElementById("selectObj").value;

//objName in javascript taken from $objName var in php that is and the beginning of the html page.
objName = <?php echo json_encode($objName); ?>;

//objInst takes the value of the dropdown menu and assigns it as the [] in objName array
objInst = objName[selectedObj];

//timestamp is set in php and imported to java
var timestamp = <?php echo $timestamp; ?>;
```

EDIT 2:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"">    </script>
    </head>
<h3>Optionen und Berechnen</h3>
    <form name="myForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    <div id="divCalc">
    </div>
    <input id="addObject" type="button" onclick="addObj()" value="Add Object">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="divAddObj" hidden="true">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="divCalc">
    </div>
    <div id="divResult"></div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" name="addObject">

    var objName;
    var selectedObj;
    var objInst;
    var timestamp = <?php echo $timestamp; ?>;

        //Start select dropdown     
        var select_element = document.createElement("select");
        select_element.setAttribute("id", "selectObj");
        select_element.setAttribute("name", "selectObject");

        options = new Array();
        objName = <?php echo json_encode($objName); ?>;
        for ( var i = 0; i < (<?php echo $arrayNum; ?>); i++ ){
            options.push(new Option(objName[i], i, false, false));
        }
            options[0].selected = true;

        for ( var option in options ){
            select_element.appendChild(options[option]);
        }
        //End select dropdown

        //check selected object
        selectedObj = document.getElementById("selectObj").value;

        objInst = objName[selectedObj];
        var timestampst = $(timestamp).val();
        var objNamest = $(objInst).val();

        $.post("sendCalc.php", {
            postobjNamest:objInst,
            posttimestampst:timestamp},
        function(data){
            $("#divResult").html(data);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `objInst`? Should you not be using `postobjNamest: objNamest` ?

Comment: objInst & timestamp may be elements like var timestamp = $('#timepstamp);
or var timestamp = document.getElementById('timestamp);

Comment: well most of the html code is written through DOM, and most of what I'm trying to pass are javascript variables that are first defined in the script. I'll make an edit though.

Comment: Can you tell me what result you get for print_r($_POST);

Comment: @SSS on the php page it just shows Array(), but on the html page it shows Array (  [posttimestampst] => 1399973296 [postobjNamest] => test2-1 )

Comment: Can you show us **your html for the input elements** and the js code where you define **timestamp** and **objInst** variables?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code  to:

```
objNamest = objInst.value;
timestampst = timestamp.value;
$.post("sendCalc.php", {
    postobjNamest: objNamest,
    posttimestampst: timestampst },
    function(data){
       $("#divResult").html(data);
});
```

Comment: Can you show us **your html for the input elements and the button** and the js code where you define **timestamp** and **objInst** variables?

Comment: Can you post the HTML sent to your browser by your server? Can you also post the JSON object objName?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `data` parameter of `$.post()`.

From the docs about `post()`:

> data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String:
>
> A plain object or string that is sent
>   to the server with the request.

Your params `postobjNamest` & `posttimestampst` do *not* exist for the `$.post()` method

It should be

```
$.post("sendCalc.php", {
    // An "on-the-fly" created JavaScript object, which is valid
    data: {
        postobjNamest: objInst,
        posttimestampst: timestamp
    },
    function(data){ 
        var content = $.parseJSON(data);
         window.console.log(content.postobjNamest);
         window.console.log(content.posttimestampst);
     }
});
```

From the docs about `parseJSON()`:

> Description: Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting
>   JavaScript object.

---

And in the PHP:

```
$objName = $_POST['postobjNamest'];
$timestamp = $_POST['posttimestampst'];

// Returning your values to client
// Don't echo them in PHP
echo json_encode(array(
        'postobjNamest' => $objName, 
        'posttimestampst' => $timestamp
    );
```

From the docs about `json_encode()`:

> json_encode — Returns the JSON representation of a value

---

The Javascript Object:

```
// Declaration
var Obj = {
    propertyOne: 'value', // string
    propertyTwo: 52.3654, // float
    methodOne: function () { 
        // your function code 
    },
    methodTwo: function () { 
        // your function code 
    }
}

//Instances
var objOne = new Obj();
objOne.methodOne();
objOne.propertyTwo;

var objTwo = new Obj();
objTwo.methodOne();
objTwo.propertyTwo;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but when I use

    $.post("sendCalc.php", {
 data: {
     postobjNamest:objInst,
     posttimestampst:timestamp},
   function(data){
    $("#divResult").html(data);
   }});

my add object button (which runs the javascript and sends post) doesn't work

Comment: show html code pls, the $_POST is containig something, now?